# Replace for loop? This function works but it takes to long time. I'm looking for ways to impove it

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe

It works but takes 40 seconds to work 1 stock 1 simple moving average. I'm a beginner, Is there any ways to replace those for loops or more efficient way to run this? I'm reading about numpy but I don't understand how it could replace a loop.

I'm trying to make a csv to store all the indicatorvalues from current period to the start of my dataframe.
I currently only have one moving average but with this speed its pointless to add anything else :)

```
def runcheck(df,adress):
    row_count = int(0)


    row_count=len(df)
    print(row_count)
    lastp = row_count-1

    row_count2 = int(0)
    mabuild = int(0)
    ma445_count = int(0)
    ma_count2 = int(0)
    row_count5 = int(0)
    row_count3 = int(0)
    row_count4 = int(0)
    resultat = int(0)
    timside_count = int(0)
    slott_count = int(0)
    sick_count = int(0)
    rad_data = []

    startT = time.time()
##    denna kollar hela vägen till baka t.ex idag.  sen igår i förrgår 
    for row in df.index:
        row_count2 += 1
        timside_count = row_count-row_count2
        if timside_count >= 445:
            for row in df.index:
                row_count5 = row_count-row_count2
                slott_count = row_count5-row_count3
                mabuild = mabuild+df.iloc[slott_count,5]
                row_count3 += 1
                row_count4 += 1
                if row_count4 == 445:
                    resultat = mabuild/row_count4
                    rad_data.append(resultat)
                    row_count3 = int(0)
                    row_count4 = int(0)
                    mabuild = int(0)
                    resultat = 0
                    break

##        sparar till csv innan loop börjar om
        with open(adress, "a") as fp:
            wr = csv.writer(fp,)
            wr.writerow(rad_data)
        rad_data.clear()

    print('Time was :', time.time()-startT)
    stop=input('')
```

Comment: You could start by removing the calls to int(). Simply use numbers, it will save a lot of function lookups.

Comment: Ok, this is definitely a [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me :) Tiger I removed all the int calls you said. It helps but still over 40 sec run time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as **too broad** for this site. @Akaisteph7 Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353), [_Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353) and [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: Numpy also uses loops "under the hood". The difference is that these loops are in compiled C code instead of in Python bytecode. That makes them faster. Furthermore, for some operations Numpy can use highly optimized scientific libraries.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ This would fit on Code Review. Not sure what your point is. It's that my reason for close vote is wrong? What are the other links for then?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 This post may fit on CR (perhaps with slightly more context). The key take-aways from those links are that [you shouldn't use the existence of CR as a reason to close a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287401/1575353). If you think it should be migrated then [flag it for moderator intervention stating why it should be migrated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266750/1575353).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce


def runcheck(df,adress):
    startT = time.time()

    rad_data = map(lambda i: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda z: df.iloc[z, 5], np.arange(i-445, i)))/445, np.arange(445, len(df.index)))

    '''
    Explanation

    list_1 = np.arange(445, len(def.index) -> Create a list of integers from 445 to len(def.index)
    rad_data = map(lambda i: function, list_1) -> Apply function (see below) to each value (i) in the generated list_1
    function = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list_2)/445 -> Take 2 consecutive values (x, y) in list_2 (see below) and sum them, repeat until one value left (i.e. sum of list_2), then divide by 445
    list_2 = map(lambda z: df.iloc[z, 5], list_3) -> Map each value (z) in list_3 (see below) to df.iloc[z, 5]
    list_3 = np.arange(i-445, i) -> Create a list of integers from i-445 to i (value i from list_1)
    '''
    # writing to your csv file outside the loop once you have all the values is better, as you remove the overhead of re-opening the file each time
    with open(adress, "a") as fp: 
        wr = csv.writer(fp,)
        for data in rad_data:
            wr.writerow([data])

    print('Time was :', time.time()-startT)
    stop=input('')
```

Not sure it works, as I don't have sample data. Let me know if there are errors and I'll try to debug!

Comment: NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined

Comment: `from functools import reduce`

Comment: from functools import reduce?

Comment: sorry for asking but how can I read about this function or understand how it works

Comment: I've made an edit, please try again. I am using functional aspects of python, here's an intro to some of the techniques: https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php

Comment: seems to work now, down to 11 secounds. I will read up on that function.
Thanks alot

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: G97, Thanks for your help once again, I have been running time.time function on my code. Feels like its only filewriting that is taking time. Do you think its nessesarry to keep it? Plan is to add 25-50 more values then do my conditions and checking if they are true over a large number of stocks if true point them out. When I time the upper parts of code its 0.0 but over the loop its 10-15 secounds per stock. Only figure out how i can reach this 445 value x periods ago and to make another value copy of this with another value then 445